# I20 rpm down to 600?

Tags: hyundai, rpm, i20

Hyundai i20 rpm down to 600 from normal rpm 800 or 850 rpm when idle.

I have cleaned throttle body but still same low rpm.

Please help it's emergency.

Comment: Does the engine still run or does it stall? Is the RPMs *always* at the 600rpm level now? How does it affect the operation of the vehicle?

Comment: The engine still runs. Yes, yes,...Rpm is always at 600. No effect on the engine performance and everything works fine. No warning signs on instrument cluster, etc etc working all fine.

Comment: Slower idle uses less fuel . In carburetor days I tried to get idle to 500 rpm.